# We're US citizens. We will arrive in Dubai T3 at 7:30 pm, 6-hour layover. How can we maximize time?

Tags: dubai

We want to maximize time for the 6-hour layover in Dubai. We're arriving at 7:30 pm at T3 with Emirates and leaving to Male at 1:30 am from T2 with flydubai. We purchased entrance tickets to go up the Burj Khalifa for the evening.

How can we get there? How much will a taxi cost? Do we still need to go to Dubai mall since we already have tickets? Can we bring our hand-carry luggage, a small trolley for my husband and a medium purse for me? Can we wear open-toe shoes and below the knee pants? Do we need to go back to T3, and then T2 on our way to Male? Where can we buy gold souvenirs? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> How can we get to BK?

You can take a cab (recommended) or the metro (may be quicker, depending on traffic).

> How much will be for a taxi?

Taxi fares are controlled strictly. There is a surcharge from the airport. All taxis are metered and charges clearly visible. They will also accept credit cards.

I believe the maximum you should pay is 100 AED.

> Do we still need to go to Dubai mall since we already have tickets?

Yes, as the entrance is from the basement floor of Dubai Mall.

> Can we bring our hand carry luggage, a small trolley for my husband and a medium purse for me?

Yes absolutely. There are luggage lockers near the drop off point for the cab in Dubai Mall. You can also take these items with you to the viewing platform.

> Can we wear open toes shoes and below the knee pants?

Yes absolutely. No issues here.

> Do we need to go back to T3 then T2 on our way to Male?

No, you will go straight to T2.

> Where can we buy gold souvenirs?

You can buy them in Dubai Mall, there is a Gold Souq area, and its very accessible from the basement once you are done with the Burj.

Some important points for your itinerary:

- The mall closes at midnight
- The tower access will close 2 hours before the mall does
- You must take a cab back from the mall, as the metro does not stop at Terminal 2.

---

***Detailed Information***

From T3, take the exit towards immigration. Depending on the day of the week, there may be a queue for you at the immigration counters. Make sure you pay the immigration fees first at the bank counters (on either side of the immigration hall).

Once you are past immigration, go straight through (don't bother waiting for your luggage as it won't be released to you).

Once you exit the terminal, take the stairs up to the metro station. It is the quickest way to get to Dubai Mall if you want to avoid traffic. You can also take a cab from the queue outside if the traffic isn't bad (again, depends on what day of week you arrive).

I would recommend the the cab ride - takes around 15 minutes (again, depends on traffic) and more importantly - it will drop you in the basement floor from where the entrance is a short walk away.

*The metro stop is clear across the main highway - so you have a good 10-15 minute walk before you even reach Dubai Mall. The metro entrance is on the top most floor on almost the opposite end of where you want to be if you want to go to the Burj. You are in for a quite a walk.*

You can find luggage lockers as soon as you enter (via the cab). They are on the basement floor. Otherwise just find your way to the entrance of the Burj Khalifa (prominent signs around, as I recall you just keep left and you'll run into it after an ice cream parlor).

The entire Burj Khalifa experience can be completed in 45 minutes (if you are quick). Normal time is 90 minutes.

Personally, when I went there (at the viewing gallery at the top) I didn't see the attraction of it and we were done in 10 minutes.

Your main issue will be trying to avoid the photographers who are scattered throughout and will ask you to pose and then photoshop you (badly) onto some scene from the tower.

The exciting part of the trip for me was the trivia and the elevator ride. YMMV.

Anyway once done and then on the way down past the gift shop - you'll be in the mall.

Good news is from here its a short walk to the Gold Souq area of the mall from where you can buy gold souvenirs.

**You must take a cab on the way back as the metro only stops at T1 and T3.** Your luggage should already be checked in, and you will already have your boarding passes - so simply head towards immigration and security, then onto your gate for the flight to Male.